# Javascript copy properties inside an object

Tags: javascript, properties, javascript-objects, object-properties

I have an object as below;

```
record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}
```

Now I want all these properties to be copied to a "row" attribute inside "record". So, it should look like;

```
record = {
    row: {
        prop1: 'X',
        prop2: 'Y',
        prop3: 'Z'
    }
}
```

While I can get that using

```
record.row = record;
```

What I want is

1. the properties prop1/prop2/prop3 to be removed as direct child of "record" after copying them inside record.row
2. The above statement also ends up repeating the properties inside the row (sort of circular thing) which I want to avoid

How can I achieve this satisfying both the conditions ?
P.S: "propX" are all simple string values, I am fine with a deep/shallow copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
let record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}

record = { ...record, row: record }
```

For older version of node, you can do this instead:

```
var record = {
  prop1: 'X',
  prop2: 'Y',
  prop3: 'Z'
};


let newRecord = {}
Object.assign(newRecord, {
  row: record
});

// console.log(newRecord)
```

Comment: Hey...thanks...I am using this within my Ember project...For some reason, this statement is failing build saying Unexpected token (at ...)

Comment: I do have Babel as dependency added

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: My Node version is 10.x

Comment: Yes...so that works ......Object.assign(record, {
  row: record
});

However the original issue still remains i.e. I want the copied attributes to be then removed as direct child of "record"

Comment: So..it is kind of cut/paste (cut as direct child of "record" and pasted inside "record.row")
...so all this should happen in the same/original "record" object

Comment: yes, this returns `record` with only a property of `row` which has three properties

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```js
record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}
record = {row:{...record}}
```

or

```js
record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}
record = Object.assign({},{row:record})
```

Comment: Hey...thanks...I am using this within my Ember project...For some reason, this statement is failing build saying Unexpected token (at ...)

Comment: Also I do have Babel as dependency added

Comment: @testndtv check again? add another way.

Comment: This one does not give a build error...but I do not see the final/updated "record" object as expected

Comment: @testndtv sorry, i forgot the assignment, check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve it? I assume you want the original variable to be overwritten.

```
record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}

var tempRecord = {record:record}

record = tempRecord
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution-1

```
var record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}
let newRecord = {row:{}}
Object.keys(record).forEach(key=> newRecord.row[key] = record[key]);
```

Solution-2

```
  var record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
  }
  let newRecord = {};

  for (let[key,value] of Object.entries(record)) {
    if (!newRecord['row']) {
      newRecord = {
        row: {}
      };
    }
    newRecord["row"][key] = value;
  }
```

Solution-3:

```
var record = {
    prop1: 'X',
    prop2: 'Y',
    prop3: 'Z'
}

record = {row:{...record}}
```